# C++ Possible Programming Mystery?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int loop = 0;
    int Pass = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    cout << "Write In A 4 Digit Number!";
    cin >> Pass;

    while (loop == 0)
    {
        guess = guess + 1;

        if (Pass == guess)
        {
            cout << "Your number is" + guess;
        }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

This mystery code is giving me random outputs. This is a program ment to guess what number you put in. Instead when you input a random number and hit enter it gives you stuff like error and YF and stuff. Try it yourself by testing the code. If you type in 1 and press enter you will get our number is printed out.

1. our number is
2. ur number is
3. r number is
4. number is
5. number is

There's some more odd also like if you enter 666 you will get: e::_S_normalize_catory catory not found and if you enter 333 ☻ will print out.

There's plenty more. Some numbers are blank but some are not.

Can someone please tell me why this happends!

CLOSED: THANKS FOR HELPING ME OUT. I CLOSE THIS NOW. YOU CAN STILL CHAT!

Comment: `"Your number is" + guess;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: When does your loop end? *Never* \*shudder\*

Comment: This is the code you should have written while trying to figure this out: `cout << "Your number is" + 3;`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the

```
cout << "Your number is" + guess;
```

to

```
cout << "Your number is " << guess;
```

In C++, adding a number to a string literal doesn't convert the number to a string; it does something else entirely (pointer arithmetic).

For a backgrounder on pointer arithmetic in C and C++, see [Everything you need to know about pointers in C](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) (especially the [last section about strings](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#strings)).

The reason your program prints out funny strings is that, once `guess` gets large enough, the `"Your number is" + guess` points to some memory after the end of the string literal, and the program prints out whatever happens to be in that memory. (Technically, you're in the realm of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and so your program could legitimately behave in all sorts of strange ways.)

Answer (score 2):

"Your number is" is a char *, and you are *adding* 'guess' to it.  This moves the pointer to somewhere other than the start of the string literal.  If the value of guess is small you will end up somewhere inside the string and it will print the subsequent part ok.  If you enter a larger number it will access somewhere completely random and cause an error.

Try:

`cout << "Your number is: " << guess;`

(To use the string + operator at least one part of the input needs to be a string.  You have a const char * and an int, so the compiler thinks you want to do pointer arithmetic.  Even if you make the string literal into a string you would also need to make guess into a char * using itoa for it to display correctly.  Much easier to stick with the stream version using <<.)

Answer (score 1):

By adding an integer value to the address of the string (`"Your number is" + guess`), you get a new address that points to some character inside the string or to what comes next. Then the `cout` statement will print all characters from there until the next null byte.

You rediscovered the joys of buffer overflow hacking...